# Reading image capture files in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap application that captures images using the camera and, later, uploads them. There are two modes of operation for camera in PhoneGap: raw base64 encoded data or a file URI.

The docs themselves say:

> Note: The image quality of pictures taken using the camera on newer
>   devices is quite good. Encoding such images using Base64 has caused
>   memory issues on some of these devices (iPhone 4, BlackBerry Torch
>   9800). Therefore, using FILE_URI as the 'Camera.destinationType' is
>   highly recommended.

So I'm keen to use FILE_URI option. This works great and you can even show the images in IMG tags. The URL looks like this:

> file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/4FE4642B-944C-449BB-9BD6-1E442E47C7CE/tmp/photo_047.jpg

However, at some point later I want to read the contents of the file to upload to a server. I was going to do this using the FileReader type. This doesn't work and I think it's because I can't access the file at the URL above.

The error code I get back from readDataUrl is 1 > `FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR = 1;`

Any ideas how I can get to the file? I tried just accessing the last part of the path (photo_047.jpg) based on another sample I saw but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just getting started with PhoneGap, and given the age of this question you may have found an answer already, but I'll give it a try anyway.

First, would you be able to use the built-in **FileTransfer** object? It takes a *file:* URI as an argument.

If **FileTransfer** won't work for you, and you need to read the file data yourself, you'll need the PhoneGap **File** objects, like **FileReader** , as you said. But most of those expect a plain pathname -- not a URI -- to specify the file to work with.  The reason you're getting NOT_FOUND_ERR is because it's trying to open a file named *file:/localhost/var...*.

Here's a quick one-liner to extract the path part from your URI:

`var path = /file:\/\/.*?(\/.*)/.exec(fileuri)[1];`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from jgarbers was of help to me but it did not solve the problem. I realized the camera stores photos in Temp folder instead of Document folder. Setting my local file system to temporary allowed it to find the correct location for the camera images.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

...

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, ...

...

var path = /file://.*?(/.*)/.exec(fileuri)[1];

Ref. above jgarbers and Rik answers (solution has been tested successfully on iOs 7)

Answer (score 0):

you can user the file transfer plugin for uploading any file to the server.

```
//// pass your file uri to the mediafie param
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    path = mediaFile.fullPath;
    name = mediaFile.name;
////your service method url
    var objUrl = http://example.com;


    ft.upload(path,
        objUrl,
        function (result) {
            alert("Success");


        },
        function (error) {
            alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: name });
}
```